# LFTP when used with proxies doesn't work

Tags: lftp

I can't seem to use LFTP with proxies that require authentification correctly on my Ubuntu server.
When I use it with proxy that doesn't require username/password everything seems fine:

```
lftp 
lftp :~> set http:proxy http://HOST:PORT 
lftp :~> set ftp:proxy http://HOST:PORT 
lftp :~> open username:password@some.ftp.site.com 
lftp username@some.ftp.site.com:~> get file.ext 
file.ext 
36352 bytes transferred in 10 seconds (3.5K/s) 
lftp username@some.ftp.site.com:~> exit
```

but when I have to put username/password there is a problem:

```
lftp 
lftp :~> set http:proxy http://proxylogin:proxypass@HOST:port 
lftp :~> set ftp:proxy http://proxylogin:proxypass@HOST:port 
lftp :~> open ftp://ftpuser:ftppass@ftpserv.com
```

answer:

```
cd: Access failed: 401 Authentication Required (~)
```

please someone help!

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to test:

```
lftp :~> set ftp:proxy http://proxylogin:proxypass@HOST:port 
lftp :~> open ftpserv.com 
lftp :~> USER ftpuser
password: ftppass
```

OR this other one to automate something:

```
lftp :~> set ftp:proxy http://proxylogin:proxypass@HOST:port 
lftp :~> open ftpserv.com 
lftp :~> USER ftpuser ftppass
```